# restoring object to default state

Tags: java, design-patterns, javac

I am applying an object pool where we are facing issues because of huge number of object creation. For the same I need a `clear()` method to clean or restore object to the default state of every object, as if it is a newly created object. Can this be done without having manually calling each method to set to default as this would lead to a chance of a bug if developer forget to update `clear()` when changing `bean class`.

Comment: Just a thought, if you always call clear() from you constructor, it would be fairly obvious to the niex developer touching the code that clear() is where object initialization happens. Not bulletproof, of course. Next, you may think of how far you can get with automatic tests. If you serialize a new and a used but cleared object and the serializations are not the same, this could be a sign of a problem, for instance.

Comment: Could you please specify your problem? Is it memory? Is it computational time? In case you have a memory problem, object pooling could proof do be of no effect (if the data does not fit into RAM, it does not fit, no fix for that except for re-thinking your data structure(s)). This seems like an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all unwanted objects automatically get collected by the garbage collector.

Another option you have to request garbage collector by using:

```
System.gc();
```

OR

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

You can `Override finalize method` in your bean class

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
//Keep some resource closing operations here
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned that the **creation** of object is the problem, not the memory (which I assume is more a time- than a memory-issue).

Comment: System.gc(); should (must) not be used in productive code. But, in this case, the garbage collector has to be customized with arguments. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely no any kind of such ready decision for your case in `Java`. If you need return pool's worker in initial state, so you have to do it by your self, I mean that you need write method which will put all needed object variables in initial values.

Meantime I would say your avoiding about huge number of object creation here is unnecessarily, until you will see in profiler significant time of this particular event. I would also say that due to complex structure of your classes (as you do not want to write this clean method by your self, I guess - they are complex) - clearing these objects them self will take comparable time to this object creation time. Pooling in `Java` in most cases is used for really expensive objects, such as threads or DB connections.